# How to record and replay htop?

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring, htop

TL;DR Is there an option to run htop in a way that will generate some report and the load it using htop later? Similar to perf record and perf report.

I'm a big fan of htop. I use it quite a lot when I want to see if I have some resource problem. e.g some process thread is taking too much cpu/memory. I was wondering if there is a way to record the data that htop use, e.g snapshots of `/proc`, and use it later in htop. I basically want to run htop on my sever and view the results later. Similar to what you can do with sar. Only that I prefer htop a lot more than the tools that come with sar.

Comment: If sar contains the data you need but you dislike the text based interfaces, try: https://sarchart.weebly.com/ or Java based kSar. Also there are other tools that you may find useful if you enjoy htop, namely atop: https://www.atoptool.nl/

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `perf`, which is fully fledged disassembler/debugger/profiler suite, `htop` is just a simple "[interactive process manager - a better top with scrolling](https://youtu.be/PEN2ZzXdpJE?t=1m52s)" (as author defines it himself in his video presentation). In version 3.0 `htop` should get support for reading kernel perf counters, which is a great improvement, but no plans has been announced for supporting advanced profiling features like those present in `perf`...

At this time, the only way one might record `htop` is by means of [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/docs/installation) or similar tools, nothing like interactive replay of a recorded performance profile...